# How do I fix this cin.ignore() for my getline()?

Tags: c++, string, getline

So I write a simple program for c++, and I run into this problem. The program basically asks for the input from user, and it will skip whatever whitespace after the input. I was trying to use `cin.ignore()` after user input, but it won't work. How would I fix it ?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    cout << "Your name: ";      
    getline(cin, s);
    cin.ignore();

    cout << "You entered: " << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to describe the problem. What are you expecting `cin.ignore()` to fix? What problem are you running into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to use `std::cin.ignore()`? Assuming you want to skip potential leading whitespace, you might want to use `std::ws`:

```
std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, s);
```

Comment: Note that newlines are also whitespace, so this also skips any presses of Enter before the first non-whitespace character